# Undefined variable but has the correct value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem. I get the information of a user via firestore and I want to create a dynamic textfield with the username. So I'm saving the name of the user in a variable. But when I call the username variable later, it is undefined. What is the problem? With console.log in `docRef.get().then(function (doc) { ... }`  the correct value is there, but the problem is at `document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + user.username;`

```
var username;
var kontostand;
var ticket;



firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

    // Get the data from the user
    docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        //console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        kontostand = doc.data().kontostand;
        ticket = doc.data().ticket;
        username = doc.data().username;
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user != null) {

      document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + username;

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";


  }
});
```

Comment: in question you are expecting ` "Welcome User : " + user.uid;` to wirk but in code you have  `"Welcome User : " + username;`, which one is correct ? you missed it by mistake ?

Comment: @warl0ck I edited the question. I copied the wrong.

Comment: @warl0ck could you explain that?

Comment: never mind it was for previous version of question

Answer (score 0):

This is because `docRef.get().then(...)` is a function which works asynchronously. This means that it returns immediately, even before a result is present, and executes its code only when the result (or failure to obtain one) is there.

Since it returns immediately, `username` will not be set, because that variable will be populated later, when the result is present.

```
// Get the data from the user
docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    //console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    kontostand = doc.data().kontostand;
    ticket = doc.data().ticket;
    username = doc.data().username;

    // not really needed here: var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    // user will be non-null, so no check required
    document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + username;

  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And how could I fill the variable  `username ` correctly?

Comment: Thank you verz much! Is there a option to save the username in variable?